# Strip HTML tags from repeatable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am writing a code where have a HTML code like this, I want to strip/replace the HTML tags inside `blog-excerpt` area with 160 character.

**After run my code showing the same text data in both div. But i need to show the actual text**

```
<div class="blog-item">
    <div class="blog-excerpt" style="color:red">
        <b>Here is the</b>  Sample Text <i> One (01) </i> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="blog-item"  style="color:blue">
    <div class="blog-excerpt">
       <b>Here is the</b>  Sample Text <i> Two (02) </i> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want to stripe the HTML tags from inside of the **`"blog-excerpt"`** div. So all the HTML code will be plain text actually and i also want to give 160 character limit for  **`"blog-excerpt"`** content.

I used the follow jquery code to do that.

```
var str = $( ".blog-excerpt" ).text();
$( ".blog-excerpt" ).text( str );
$(".blog-excerpt").text(function(index, currentText) {
return currentText.substr(0, 160);
```

And it works BUT Unfortunately there showing same text in both `"blog-item"` after run my jquery code.

Please help me to finish that code.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved that issue with the following code. `$( ".blog-excerpt" ).text( str );`
It was wrong on my code. I deleted that and it works

```js
    var str = $( ".blog-excerpt" ).text();
    $(".blog-excerpt").text(function(index, currentText) {
    return currentText.substr(0, 160);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-item">
    <div class="blog-excerpt" style="color:red">
     <b>Here is the</b>  Sample Text <i> One (01) </i> 
 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-item"  style="color:blue">
    <div class="blog-excerpt">
       <b>Here is the</b>  Sample Text <i> Two (02) </i> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you want 160, why are yuo using 175?

Comment: Oh sorry typing mistake. Let me fix